# Upload to Google Drive using CRON without logged-in/manual?

Tags: php, cron, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files into Google Drive using the Google Drive API but the problem is that I have to be logged-in every time. I searched a lot but no luck.

Is there any way I can do authentication process without manual and logged-in intervention?

Comment: add more description to your question. How exactly are you trying to upload your files? I see a php tag in ques.

Comment: Look at the documentation for oauth2

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it correctly, you should only have to authenticate once save the refresh token, and use the refresh token in all your other calls.

Second option would be  a service account but that is tricky as files are uploaded to the service account, unless you give it permission to upload to your own Google drive account.